# How to start and stop video recorder from android application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I need to launch video recorder on click of the button from my application.When user start the recording I need to show count down timer and when the time elapsed video recorder should close automatically.

I searched on many forums and got suggestions to use custom camera recorder, but I don't want use it as I will loose native features like flash,front camera etc.

So the idea is to launch the native video recorder and show timer and when time expires close the recorder and come back to application.

I am able to launch the recorder by 'startActivity()' with camera intent but not able to set timer and close the recorder. Please let me know if it is poosible to do it.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                // Launch an intent to capture video from MediaStore
                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
            }
        });

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO) {

                Uri videoUri = data.getData();
               String filePath = getPath(videoUri);
                Log.d("LOGCAT", "Video path is: " + filePath );
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to post with your working code.the code filter is not working so the hint is. In your On activity result block use timer if timer is equal to 0 close the Camera (if you do not close the camera the activity result will do that for you) Intent and start the your main activity.